# Excel: Action based on color and content

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a solution for a particular situation: I will need any selected or given cell to:

1. return a value stored in another cell if the selected or given cell is empty but has color filling;
2. no action if the selected or given cell has color filling but not empty (has value).

Thank you all!

My code is as below, and the issue is syntax error:

```vb
Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)

ColorIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex

End Function

Sub installCurrent()

Dim cell As Range
Set cell = ActiveCell

    If Cell(ActiveCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 16 and
        IsEmpty() = True Then
    cell(ActiveCell).Value = cell(E, ActiveCell.Row).Value
        
End Sub
```

Updated on 1:34PM 08182020

```vb
    Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)
    ColorIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex 
    End Function 
____________
    Sub installCurrent()
 
    Dim Cell As Range Set 
    Cell = ActiveCell 

    If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16 and 
        IsEmpty(cell.Value) = True Then 

    Cell.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "E").Value 
  
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for you list of needs, unfortunately this will require vba and Stack Overflow is not a code for me site or teach me to code site.  If you have code that is not working, please [edit] the post to include the code you have tried and explain where it errors.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you! I am writing it and will update the post soon.

Comment: Replace all instances of `Cell(ActiveCell)` with just `Cell`. Then change `IsEmpty()` to `IsEmpty(cell.Value)`. Then change `cell(E, ActiveCell.Row).Value` to `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "E").Value`.

Comment: @BigBen I still get the syntax error after correction and let me try to paste the current code down here. Thank you!                                                                                                 Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)

ColorIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex

End Function

Sub installCurrent()

Dim Cell As Range
Set Cell = ActiveCell

    If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16 and
        IsEmpty(cell.Value) = True Then
    Cell.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "E").Value
                  
    End If
    
End Sub

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code instead of posting in comments.

Comment: @BigBen I have updated it, thank you!

Comment: That `Set` should be at the beginning of the next line

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you! I moved the `Set`to the right place, and it was the `Sub` line that I got the yellow mark.

Comment: Is that line of underscores in your actual code ? That's not going to compile.  Also if you want a line break after the `And` you need to use the underscore line continuation.

Comment: @TimWilliams The line is not in the code, and you pointed out the exact problem in my code! After fixing now it's working! Thank you so much